# Does Bazel actually require Python?

Tags: bazel

The Bazel install instructions say that Python is required. However, I used the Linux installer without Python and it seems to work.

Does Bazel actually require Python for non-Python builds, such as C++ and Go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it doesn't, and your success to build without Python proves that.